# Bulk operations and web services

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I have a web service that allows a client to provision information to the server.
Although, each provisioning method of the service allows provisioning multiple pieces of information at once, I don't think it is appropriated to provisioning of huge amount of information.

Therefore, I'm looking for an efficient way to implement bulk provisioning through web services.

Assume no particular application protocol is used. Therefore, I would like to hear if one technology is more appropriated than another for this kind of operation (e.g. REST is more appropriated than SOAPoverHTTP).

Thanks,
Mickael